# Testing Motor calls with IOLoop

Tags: python-2.7, unit-testing, python-unittest, tornado-motor

I'm running unittests in the callbacks for motor database calls, and I'm successfully catching AssertionErrors and having them surface when running nosetests, but the AssertionErrors are being caught in the wrong test. The tracebacks are to different files.

My unittests look generally like this:

```
def test_create(self):
    @self.callback
    def create_callback(result, error):
        self.assertIs(error, None)
        self.assertIsNot(result, None)
    question_db.create(QUESTION, create_callback)
    self.wait()
```

And the unittest.TestCase class I'm using looks like this:

```
class MotorTest(unittest.TestCase):
    bucket = Queue.Queue()
    # Ensure IOLoop stops to prevent blocking tests
    def callback(self, func):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            try:
                func(*args, **kwargs)
            except Exception as e:
                self.bucket.put(traceback.format_exc())
            IOLoop.current().stop()
        return wrapper

    def wait(self):
        IOLoop.current().start()
        try:
            raise AssertionError(self.bucket.get(block = False))
        except Queue.Empty:
            pass
```

The errors I'm seeing:

```
======================================================================
FAIL: test_sync_user (app.tests.db.test_user_db.UserDBTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/----/Documents/app/app-Server/app/tests/db/test_user_db.py", line 39, in test_sync_user
    self.wait()
  File "/Users/----/Documents/app/app-Server/app/tests/testutils/mongo.py", line 25, in wait
    raise AssertionError(self.bucket.get(block = False))
AssertionError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/----/Documents/app/app-Server/app/tests/testutils/mongo.py", line 16, in wrapper
    func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/----/Documents/app/app-Server/app/tests/db/test_question_db.py", line 32, in update_callback
    self.assertEqual(result["question"], "updated question?")
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Where the error is reported to be in UsersDbTest but is clearly in test_questions_db.py (which is QuestionsDbTest)

I'm having issues with nosetests and asynchronous tests in general, so if anyone has any advice on that, it'd be greatly appreciated as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't fully understand your code without an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), but I'd say you're taking an unwise approach to async testing in general.

The particular problem you face is that you don't wait for your test to complete (asynchronously) before leaving the test function, so there's work still pending in the IOLoop when you resume the loop in your next test. Use Tornado's own "testing" module -- it provides convenient methods for starting and stopping the loop, and it recreates the loop between tests so you don't experience interference like what you're reporting. Finally, it has extremely convenient means of testing coroutines.

For example:

```
import unittest
from tornado.testing import AsyncTestCase, gen_test

import motor

# AsyncTestCase creates a new loop for each test, avoiding interference
# between tests.
class Test(AsyncTestCase):
    def callback(self, result, error):
        # Translate from Motor callbacks' (result, error) convention to the
        # single arg expected by "stop".
        self.stop((result, error))

    def test_with_a_callback(self):
        client = motor.MotorClient()
        collection = client.test.collection
        collection.remove(callback=self.callback)

        # AsyncTestCase starts the loop, runs until "remove" calls "stop".
        self.wait()

        collection.insert({'_id': 123}, callback=self.callback)

        # Arguments passed to self.stop appear as return value of "self.wait".
        _id, error = self.wait()
        self.assertIsNone(error)
        self.assertEqual(123, _id)

        collection.count(callback=self.callback)
        cnt, error = self.wait()
        self.assertIsNone(error)
        self.assertEqual(1, cnt)

    @gen_test
    def test_with_a_coroutine(self):
        client = motor.MotorClient()
        collection = client.test.collection
        yield collection.remove()
        _id = yield collection.insert({'_id': 123})
        self.assertEqual(123, _id)
        cnt = yield collection.count()
        self.assertEqual(1, cnt)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

(In this example I create a new MotorClient for each test, which is a good idea when testing applications that use Motor. Your actual application **must not** create a new MotorClient for each operation. For decent performance you must create **one** MotorClient when your application begins, and use that same one client throughout the process's lifetime.)

Take a look at the testing module, and particularly the gen_test decorator:

http://tornado.readthedocs.org/en/latest/testing.html

These test conveniences take care of many details related to unittesting Tornado applications.

I gave a talk and wrote an article about testing in Tornado, there's more info here:

http://emptysqua.re/blog/eventually-correct-links/

Comment: Awesome, thanks I'll take a look at these and report back

Comment: Great. I added a note about recreating the MotorClient in tests but using a single long-lived client in a real application.

Comment: Right! When I was using the same MotorClient and running mocked applications on threads, it was complaining about switching contexts across threads - since clients need to live and be accessed on the same thread right?

Comment: That's correct. Motor is designed to be used in a single-threaded application. (Which is how Tornado applications are typically designed anyway -- at least, the IOLoop typically does most work on the main thread with occasional blocking tasks delegated to a ThreadPoolExecutor.) Since I assumed, in Motor, that you'll use Motor from a single thread, I used greenlets freely in Motor with no protection against thread-switching. But greenlets don't like running on a different thread from the one they started on.